# How to store variable data in success ajax to global variable (and call it in another function)

Tags: json

Here is my code.

```
<head>
<script>
var myGlobal ={};
</script>
</head>

<body>

$(function ()

 { 

 $.ajax({  
      url: 'test.php',                      
      data: "",
      dataType: 'json',                   
      success: function(data)
      {
        var vname = data.name; 
        my_global.push(data.name);
      }


alert('The user selected: ' + my_global.newval); // i will use this value(vname value)
```

I would like to use `VNAME` value in other function..

Comment: i tried to call it like this but my_global.newval is undefined

Comment: by the way, the first line has var my_global={};

Comment: my php file is as simple as this.

'<?php
$name = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16tUQr8xSKJjffQv9wKT_CmxpJqs-htF54M1V5fcUDxQ/edit';
$pass_back_name = array("status"=>"ok","name"=>$name);

echo json_encode($pass_back_name);

?>
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the code in the same script tags. What you wrote won't even work. The ajax code will just be displayed as text and not handled as script.

Comment: i see, thanks! i put all the code inside one script tag, it is quite a mess but this is the only way. anyway thanks!